# How can I hide a specific div when its clicked using an event listener?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The thing I want to accomplish it's to hide the specific div you clicked, and show another one instead, I already tried some things but didn't work

One of them was this, as you will see I was trying its to hide the clicked element passing the id of the element by a parameter but didn't work

```js
var el = document.getElementById(obj);
        el.style.display = 'none';
    }
```

This is how it should work: https://www.screencast.com/t/WGeokVkv

Until now I've had accomplish showing the next sibling of the clicked element, but I can't hide the one that was clicked either I can't hide the next sibling when its clicked again

How can I do that?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css">
    <!-- Our css -->
    <title>FAQ</title>
    <style>
      
        .card{
            box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px #000000;
            border-radius: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
        }
        .fa-question-circle{
            font-size: 2rem;
            color: #FFC600;
        }
        .card-subtitle{
            font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
            color: #31261B !important;
        }
        .hr-yellow-border{
            border: 2px solid #FFC600 ;
        }
        .card-text{
            color: #315470 !important;
            font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }
        .hr-grey-border{
            border: 2px solid #AB989D ;
        }
        .labels-text{
            font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }
       .labels-wrapper{
            background: #315470 !important;
            height: 3rem;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center ;
            /*Take care with the transition*/
            transition: 0.4s;
        }
        div.col-11 > .panel > p {
            font-size: small;
        }
        .plus-icon{
            cursor: pointer;
            transition: 0.4s;
            display: inline;
        }
        .panel{
            display: none;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div class="col-9">
            <br>
            <div class="card" style="height: min-content;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <i class="fas fa-question-circle d-flex justify-content-center mb-3"></i>
                    
                    <div class="col-11 mx-auto">
                        <hr class="hr-yellow-border">
                        <br>
                        <div class="labels-wrapper d-flex justify-content-between" id="question" onClick="hide('question')">
                            <h5 class="ml-2 text-white labels-text my-auto"> How do I access the event on the day of the conference?</h5><h4 class="plus-icon ml-auto mr-2 text-warning my-auto" id="question" onClick="hide('question')">+</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel">
                            <div class="row">
                                <h4 class="card-text ml-3">How do I access the event on the day of the conference?</h4><h4 class="plus-icon ml-auto mr-4 text-warning">-</h4>
                            </div>
                            <hr class="hr-grey-border">
                            <p class="ml-3">On October 15, 2020 at 10:00 AM EST, the login button will accept your registration credentials to access the online platform</p>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>

<!-- Bootstrap and jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("labels-wrapper");
    var i;
    //var question = document.getElementById("question")
    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            /* Toggle between adding and removing the "active" class,
            to highlight the button that controls the panel */
            //this.classList.toggle("panel");

            /* Toggle between hiding and showing the active panel */
            var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
            if (panel.style.display === "block") {
                panel.style.display = "none";
            } else {
                panel.style.display = "block";
            }
        });
    }
    function hide(obj) {

    var el = document.getElementById(obj);
        el.style.display = 'none';

    }
</script>
<script>
   
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can we use jQuery?

Comment: @LaurentC Yes no problem with that

Comment: OK well I put both, but the jQuery solution is preferred because it involves progressive fade in and out (with opacity, etc.),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your code is not working because flex library has style `display:flex!important` if you add `display:none` its will be override by library style due to `important`. In your javascript you have do it same way.

here is running snippet. Added solution to explain why its not working you can optimise code more.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("labels-wrapper");  
var i;
//var question = document.getElementById("question")
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    /* Toggle between adding and removing the "active" class,
    to highlight the button that controls the panel */
    //this.classList.toggle("panel");

    /* Toggle between hiding and showing the active panel */
   // console.log(this);
   // this.style.display = "none!important";
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}

function hide(obj) {
 console.log(obj);
  var el = document.getElementById(obj); 
  el.setAttribute('style', 'display:none !important');

}

function openQuestion(obj) {

  var el = document.getElementById(obj); 
  console.log(obj);
  el.setAttribute('style', 'display:block');
  var panel = el.nextElementSibling;
  panel.style.display = "none";

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- Bootstrap css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css">
  <!-- Our css -->
  <title>FAQ</title>
  <style>
    .card {
      box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px #000000;
      border-radius: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
    }
    
    .fa-question-circle {
      font-size: 2rem;
      color: #FFC600;
    }
    
    .card-subtitle {
      font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
      color: #31261B !important;
    }
    
    .hr-yellow-border {
      border: 2px solid #FFC600;
    }
    
    .card-text {
      color: #315470 !important;
      font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    
    .hr-grey-border {
      border: 2px solid #AB989D;
    }
    
    .labels-text {
      font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    
    .labels-wrapper {
      background: #315470 !important;
      height: 3rem;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      /*Take care with the transition*/
      transition: 0.4s;
    }
    
    div.col-11>.panel>p {
      font-size: small;
    }
    
    .plus-icon {
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: 0.4s;
      display: inline;
    }
    
    .panel {
      display: none;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <div class="col-9">
      <br>
      <div class="card" style="height: min-content;">
        <div class="card-body">
          <i class="fas fa-question-circle d-flex justify-content-center mb-3"></i>

          <div class="col-11 mx-auto">
            <hr class="hr-yellow-border">
            <br>
            <div class="labels-wrapper d-flex justify-content-between" id="question" onClick="hide('question')">
              <h5 class="ml-2 text-white labels-text my-auto"> How do I access the event on the day of the conference?</h5>
              <h4 class="plus-icon ml-auto mr-2 text-warning my-auto" id="question" onClick="hide('question')">+</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel" onClick="openQuestion('question')">
              <div class="row">
                <h4 class="card-text ml-3">How do I access the event on the day of the conference?</h4>
                <h4 class="plus-icon ml-auto mr-4 text-warning">-</h4>
              </div>
              <hr class="hr-grey-border">
              <p class="ml-3">On October 15, 2020 at 10:00 AM EST, the login button will accept your registration credentials to access the online platform</p>
            </div>
            <br>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Bootstrap and jQuery -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I just explained why it’s not work giving example. It can better and less line of code to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Update: Demo with complete code as requested by OP.

```js
function toggleDivs() {
  $("#div1").toggle();
  $("#div2").toggle();
}
```

```css
.div {
  margin:50px;
  height:200px;width:200px;background:blue;
}

#div2 {
  background:red;display:none;
}

#div1 {z-index:10;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="toggleDivs()">Toggler</button>


<div class="div" id="div1"></div>
<div class="div" id="div2"></div>
```

Comment: passing the slow parameter is optional.

Comment: Your answer looks good but I did just put it and doesn't work for me, maybe can you an example or with my snippet, please

Comment: Sure, try this https://codepen.io/larrytherabbit/pen/OJNQagO

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, you can use `toggle()` function to show or hide the element on click.

`$('#question').toggle();`

```
$('#question').click(function(){
   $(this).toggle();
});
```

or if you wish to use class instead of ID attribute, you use event delegation to target the specific element.

```
$('.question').on('click', function(){
   $(this).toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

I remove same - icon in html.

This can change the icon with js

```
$(this).children(".plus-icon").text("+");// for + icon
$(this).children(".plus-icon").text("-");// for - icon
```

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("labels-wrapper");

for (var i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
       
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.display === "block") {
            panel.style.display = "none";
            $(this).children(".plus-icon").text("+");
        } else {
            panel.style.display = "block";
           $(this).children(".plus-icon").text("-");
        }
    });
}
```

```css
.card{
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px #000000;
    border-radius: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
}
.fa-question-circle{
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: #FFC600;
}
.card-subtitle{
    font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
    color: #31261B !important;
}
.hr-yellow-border{
    border: 2px solid #FFC600 ;
}
.card-text{
    color: #315470 !important;
    font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.hr-grey-border{
    border: 2px solid #AB989D ;
}
.labels-text{
    font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.labels-wrapper{
    background: #315470 !important;
    height: 3rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center ;
    /*Take care with the transition*/
    transition: 0.4s;
}
div.col-11 > .panel > p {
    font-size: small;
}
.plus-icon{
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.4s;
    display: inline;
}
.panel{
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css">
    <!-- Our css -->
    <title>FAQ</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="col-11">
            <br>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <i class="fas fa-question-circle d-flex justify-content-center"></i>
                    <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <hr class="hr-yellow-border">
                        <br>
                        <div class="labels-wrapper d-flex justify-content-between" id="question">
                            <h5 class="ml-2 text-white labels-text my-auto"> How do I access the event on the day of the conference?</h5>
                            <h4 class="plus-icon ml-auto mr-2 text-warning my-auto">+</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel">
                            <p class="mt-2">On October 15, 2020 at 10:00 AM EST, the login button will accept your registration credentials to access the online platform</p>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>

<!-- Bootstrap and jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
   
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Hguedez can you try this. The icon change with js. This so silly method. to avoid in html two similar tag remove (for heading + icon and for - icon ).